# Table custom class removed in front end

Tags: typo3

I am using Typo3 V6.2. 
I create a style table-1 for the my custom tables inserted with the RTE. 
Everything is OK and I can select the table-1 style in  the table properties panel.

But in front end Typo3 generates the following code : .

I guess I have somme TS to write to allow TYPo3 to use this class un FE, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following TypoScript setup configuration allows the frontend parser to keep your individual table css class *yourCSSClass*:

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.externalBlocks.table.stdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.table.fixAttrib.class.list:= addToList(yourCSSClass)
```

Comment: would be nice to mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem :)